# change keymap for numpad, do I need remove the keybindings?

Tags: interface, sculpting, keymap

I want to change all my keymaps in the following way in sculpt mode: numpad 1 to 9 keymaps as well as . and / *

My question is, do I need to remove all keymaps that are bound to these keys in the keymap, even if it's outside of sculpt mode?

The reason is that I want to use the numpad instead of the keyboard when sculpting, so technically, this only needs to work in sculpt mode and not in other modes.

Comment: I doubt you can without causing all sorts of chaos! If you click the Key-Binding search option on the Preferences > Keymap tab and then type in 'numpad' you'll be able to see just how much those keys are used, particularly if you scroll down the list and expand the 3D View section! If you can say **why** you want to do that and [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/312073/edit) the explanation into your question someone here might have a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, I followed your suggestion and made the changes in the edit!